# How to prove someone is a Realtor on my website

Tags: web-development, looking-for-a-script, authentication

My boss would like me to have some sort of a "login" for Realtors. The point is to have a certain portion of the site only available to Realtors. Initially he thought we could check their name and license number, but that information is publicly available (usually on their business card).

Is there a global database I can link to that all Realtors are a part of, or some other way that I can make sure someone is a Realtor before forwarding them to the appropriate section of the website?

This needs to function for Realtors in all states of the United States. I'm not sure that such a national database even exists, and if it does, how I would be able to access it.

Thank you for your time and input!

Comment: This is a classic: "How do I know someone on the internet is really who they are". In Europe, there are different methods on how to check if someone's real (in Germany its PostIdent). In the end, you will only know for sure if you meet them in person, check their SSN or anyother way to check for their real ID.

Answer (score 1):

Most Realtors will be associated with the NRDS. A online datebase of Realtors, check out http://www.realtor.org/realtororg.nsf/pages/nrdsguide?opendocument

You could then have your staff check to see if they are members of the NRDS then process the logins. Best way forward would be setting registees to unapproved then once confirmed they can be set to approved on the account settings.